# Mockito - Mock dependency without injection

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I've been looking at forums all day trying to mock a class, but none of the solutions have worked for me, and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong (I'm new to Java testing).

I have this (renamed) class that I want to test, mainly each if condition to ensure they work:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static List<Object> MyClass(@NotNull Session session, @NotNull MyObject updated, @NotNull Mode mode)
    throws Exception {
        ModeList modes = MyUtil.geModes(mode);

        try {
            final Transaction tr = updated.getTransaction();
            MyObject original;

            if(tr == null) {
                original = new Foo().getCurrentBar(session, updated.getKey(), null, "en");
            } else {
                original = new Foo().getOtherBar(session,
                                                 updated.getKey(),
                                                 tr.getProp1().intValue(),
                                                 tr.getProp2().intValue(),
                                                 "en");
            }

            return SomeClass.check(updated, original, modes);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Please note I can't change this (or the Foo class) / add dependency injection, it needs to be tested as is. I have tried mockito, powerMock mock, mockStatic, partial mocks, etc, they all fail for one reason or another, and the real getCurrentBar / getOtherBar get called.

I may be getting tunnel vision at this point, but please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong, it should use a factory to get Foo, so you can mock the factory. But since you can't modify it then the next best thing is to use PowerMock.

You can follow this guide: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor make sure you do not forget the @RunWith and @PrepareForTest annotations.